# Using GetSchedule API

Tags: api, outlook, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the free busy api and i have noticed that when making requests to

POST /me/calendar/getSchedule with the body

Request body:

```
{        
     "schedules":["alex@djayasee.onmicrosoft.com", "alexw@djayasee.onMicrosoft.com"],
     ...
}
```

if one of the email addresses here is miss-typed, the whole request fails with an `ErrorNonExistentMailbox`. Imagine having 100 emails and all of them failing because of just one. This  seem less than ideal.
I need a way to verify that the emails exist before i make this call. i cannot afford to make this call for each email (too expensive...and i have a lot of email addresses).
Customers are responsible for inputting this information so it is certainly prone to errors. 
Is there an endpoint in the graph api that verifies that email addresses exist (valid)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the getSchedule can support looking up free or busy information for up to 20 entities at once (applies to the number of users identified individually or as members of a distribution list, and to the number of resources as well), so if you have more than emails then unfortunately you have to check it one by one. 
Also, the GetScheduleAPI under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and use of these APIs in production applications are generally not recommended.